# copy assignment operator besides template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, copy-assignment

I have a class

```
class A : public B
{
public:
    // 1st copy assignment with parameter pack
    template<class Arg>
    A& operator=(Arg&& arg)
    {
        B::operator=(std::forward<Args>(arg));
        return *this;
    }

    // 2nd copy assignment with const A&
    A& operator=(const A& arg)
    {
        // some code
    }
};
```

The 2nd one is not called for the following

```
A a, b;
a = b;
```

How to make compiler call the 2nd one for the above code?

Comment: What kind of an `operator=` takes anything other than exactly one parameter. Why do you need a parameter pack for the first `operator=`? Looks like you're looking for a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @SamVarshavchikS you are right. I will edit it.